# Loading files in existing table

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

In sybase ase. Is there anyway to load a file into a table without using bcp?
I read something about LOAD TABLE statement but it doesn't work for sybase ase.

Comment: The only tool Sybase provide is BCP. You can obviously write a perl, python or similar script to do it as well.

What's the reason you don't want to use BCP as this will be by far the quickest option to load the data?

Comment: It's not that I don't want to use it. I'm just exploring what other options sybase ase has.

Comment: There are probably some third party products which have wrappers over BCP (DBArtisan and RapidSQL spring to mind) which have import/export functions which wrap around BCP and make it more straightforward instead of the standard command line.

You also have the option to use say Microsoft SSIS or similar with a suitable ODBC/OLEDB driver to connect to Sybase.